# importerror catkin_pkg

Tags: ros, installation, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Problem

I reinstalled ROS1 Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 since I realized I had been using pip, apt, and virtualenvs in the wrong way.

In my system environment, I installed ROS Kinetic following the guidelines which worked fine. However when I run

```
sudo rosdep init
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
    from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .lookup import RosdepDefinition, RosdepView, RosdepLookup, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .rospkg_loader import RosPkgLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospkg_loader.py", line 37, in <module>
    import catkin_pkg.package
ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.package
```

I had solved this before by installing it with pip instead of with apt but this apparently isn't the recommended method. I've also encountered other similar import errors before where python doesn't recognize packages installed with apt.

### Details

`dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg` yields:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.6.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/catkin_find_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_test_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_prepare_release
/usr/bin/catkin_package_version
/usr/bin/catkin_tag_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_generate_changelog
```

`dpkg -L ros-kinetic-catkin` yields:

```
/.
/opt
/opt/ros
/opt/ros/kinetic
/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin-0.7.11.egg-info
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/workspace_vcs.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/package_version.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/tidy_xml.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/cmake.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/tidy_xml.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/init_workspace.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/terminal_color.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/test_results.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/environment_cache.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/workspace.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/package_version.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/init_workspace.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/__init__.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/__init__.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/environment_cache.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/workspace_vcs.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/cmake.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/terminal_color.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/test_results.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/workspace.pyc
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig/catkin.pc
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make.bash
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_python_setup.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/debug_message.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/shell.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/list_insert_in_workspace_order.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.zsh.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/rosinstall.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env-hook.context.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.sh.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/relay.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bat.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/Doxyfile.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.bash.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env.bat.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/safe_execute_install.cmake.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/_setup_util.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkgConfig.cmake.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/python_distutils_install.sh.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.sh.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/__init__.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/python_distutils_install.bat.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/cfg-extras.context.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/generate_cached_setup.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkg.context.pc.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkgConfig-version.cmake.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/order_packages.context.py.in
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em/pkg.pc.em
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/platform
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/platform/lsb.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/platform/windows.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/platform/ubuntu.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_add_env_hooks.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/list_append_deduplicate.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin_make.bash
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/string_starts_with.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_download.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/interrogate_setup_dot_py.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/tests.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/catkin_download_test_data.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/download_checkmd5.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/run_tests.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/remove_test_results.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/list_append_unique.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/find_program_required.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_libraries.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_install_python.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig-version.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/bz2.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/threads.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/libraries.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/doxygen.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_generate_environment.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_destinations.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_metapackage.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/legacy.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/order_paths.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/atomic_configure_file.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/LICENSE
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/package.xml
/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh
/opt/ros/kinetic/.rosinstall
/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_topological_order
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_package_version
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_test_results
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make_isolated
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_prepare_release
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_find
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_init_workspace
/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.zsh
/opt/ros/kinetic/_setup_util.py
/opt/ros/kinetic/.catkin
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ros-kinetic-catkin
/usr/share/doc/ros-kinetic-catkin/changelog.Debian.gz
```

`dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules` yields:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.6.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.6.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.6.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.6.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/metapackage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/tool_detection.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/terminal_color.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cmake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/package.xml.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/metapackage.cmake.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_dependency.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspace_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_membership.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/prepare_release.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/create_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/test_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/generate_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/tag_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/find_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspaces.py
```

`which python` yields:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

on Python 2.7.12

`echo $PYTHONPATH` yields:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/achille/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/home/achille/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/achille/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

`echo $PATH` yields:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/achille/bin:/home/achille/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` yields:

```
['', '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/achille/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn-0.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/joblib-0.12.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setproctitle-1.1.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/multiprocess-0.70.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ruamel.yaml-0.15.41-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill-0.2.8.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trimesh-2.31.9-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imageio-2.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py-2.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvxopt-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_video-1.1.10-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_image-0.14.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-5.5.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-3.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opencv_python-3.4.1.15-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask-0.18.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudpickle-0.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.4.0a1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/colorlog-3.1.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msgpack-0.5.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy-1.1.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svg.path-2.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Rtree-0.8.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Shapely-1.6.4.post1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future-0.16.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyWavelets-0.5.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplegeneric-0.8.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect-4.6.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pathlib2-2.3.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpmath-1.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/achille/Documents/peanut_robotics/dexnet_ws/src/meshpy', '/home/achille/Documents/peanut_robotics/dexnet_ws/src/dex-net/src', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296593/importerror-catkin_pkg/) by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
What version of the modules do you have installed? `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules`

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
Updated the question with that output: `0.4.6`

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
And where is the `catkin_pkg` module being found? `python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)"`

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
That command is the one that's not working: `ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg`. I tried all instructions in related questions.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
Can you share the search path: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
updated the question

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
Please try to unset the `PYTHONPATH` by invoking `unset PYTHONPATH`. Then try `python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)"` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` again.

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
The import still fails, even after restarting the terminal. `sys.path` does contain `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` now though.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
`sys.path` already contained `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` before. Are there any other paths before that one now? If yes, please check there content since they might interfere with the lookup.

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
You're right, missed that in the diff. Now most packages come before that one in the list. What should I be checking for? Can or should I reset this list? Should I explicitly add this line to the beginning of `PYTHONPATH`?

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-06**:
I added it to the front of the list through `PYTHONPATH` so that it's first (after `''`) in the list. The import still errors.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-07-10**:
What's the output of `import catkin_pkg`, and if that works, what's the output of `import inspect; inspect.getsourcefile(catkin_pkg)` ?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-07-10**:
Also, what's the output of `import imp; imp.find_module('catkin_pkg')` ?

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-10**:
As I mentioned above, `import catkin_pkg` only works when I do `pip install catkin_pkg`. When I do that, I get ``/home/achille/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg`for both`imp`and`inspect`. Without the pip install, obviously neither works.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-07-10**:
Any change in behavior after reinstalling python-catkin-pkg-modules? `sudo apt install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg-modules`

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2018-07-10**:
Not sure why or how but that did it! Please do add it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know the cause, but happy to hear the problem went away after running `sudo apt install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg-modules`.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1